# How to take duplicated values from the several lists?

Tags: python, list

I have several lists in python, and I would like to take only values which are in each list, is there any function to do it directly?

for example I have:

```
{'a','b','c','d','e'},{'a','g','c','d','h','e'}, {'i','b','m','d','e','a'}
```

and I want to make one list which contains

```
{'a','d','e'}
```

but i don't know how many lists I actually have, cause it's dependent on value 'i'.

thanks for any help!

Comment: what is your criteria for selecting an element ?

Comment: 'e' and 'a' are not in all the those lists you've presented ( lists are not really presented like that )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if the elements are unique and hashable (and order doesn't matter in the result), you can use [set](http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html) intersection:  e.g.:

```
 common_elements = list(set(list1).intersection(list2).intersection(list3))
```

This is functionally equivalent to:

```
 common_elements = list( set(list1) & set(list2) & set(list3) )
```

The `&` operator only works with sets whereas the the `intersection` method works with any iterable.

If you have a list of lists and you want the intersection of all of them, you can do this easily:

```
 common_elements = list( set.intersection( * map(set, your_list_of_lists) ) )
```

*special thanks to DSM for pointing this one out*

Or you could just use a loop:

```
 common_elements = set(your_list_of_lists[0])
 for elem in your_list_of_lists[1:]:
     common_elements = common_elements.intersection(elem)  #or common_elements &= set(elem) ...
 else:
     common_elements = list(common_elements)
```

Note that if you really want to get the order that they were in the original list, you can do that using a simple sort:

```
common_elements.sort( key = lambda x, your_list_of_lists[0].index(x) )
```

By construction, there is no risk of a `ValueError` being raised here.

Comment: `list(set.intersection(*map(set, s)))`?

Comment: @DSM -- Brilliant.  I'll add that.  (much nicer than my reduce atrocity) -- I didn't realize that `intersection` could take multiple arguments.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 3):

Just to put a one-liner on the table:

```
l=['a','b','c','d','e'],['a','g','c','d','h'], ['i','b','m','d','e']  
reduce(lambda a, b: a & b, map(set, l))
```

or

```
from operator import and_
l=['a','b','c','d','e'],['a','g','c','d','h'], ['i','b','m','d','e']  
reduce(and_, map(set, l))
```

Comment: One click away from moderator tools now (+1) -- your reduce is nicer than mine was :)

Comment: I thought: *finally a use for reduce!*. But then there was DSM with his `set.intersection(*map(set, l))`.

Comment: Yeah, I thought the same thing.  I'm beginning to think that `reduce` is pretty useless (and I even like functional programming tools like `map` and `filter` more than most pythonists) ...

Answer (score 1):

You need make set from first list, then use set's `.intersection()` method.

```
a, b, c = ['a','b','c','d','e'], ['a','g','c','d','h'], ['i','b','m','d','e']
exists_in_all = set(a).intersection(b).intersection(c)
```

**Updated.** 
Simplified according to **mgilson**'s comment.

Comment: No need to make `b` and `c` into sets first.

Answer (score 0):

```
from operator import and_

import operator
a = [['a','b','c','d','e'],['a','g','c','d','h','e'], ['i','b','m','d','e','a']]
print list(reduce(operator.and_, map(set, a)))
```

it will give you the commeen element from the list

```
['a', 'e', 'd']
```